# Minimize the number of nonzero elements of a matrix through elementary row operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

Is there a general method to minimize the number of nonzero elements of a real rectangular matrix through elementary row operations?

I am looking for something analogous to Gaussian elimination, that instead of returning a matrix in row echelon form, returns a similar matrix that is as sparse as possible.